# Smoothness of a map between $\Bbb {RP}^n$ and $\Bbb{RP}^k$

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I would like to prove the following statement.

If $P: \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \backslash \{0\} \to \mathbb{R}^{k+1} \backslash \{0\}$ is smooth and homogeneous of degree $d$, then the map $\widetilde P: \mathbb{RP}^n \to \mathbb{RP}^k$ defined by $\widetilde P([x]) = [P(x)]$ is smooth.

If two charts $\varphi, \psi$ are given in $\mathbb{RP}^n$ and $\mathbb{RP}^k$, respectively, I get the expression $\varphi \circ \widetilde P \circ \psi^{-1} (x_1, ..., x_n) = \varphi \circ [P(x_1, ... ,x_{i-1},1,x_{i_1}, ... x_n)]$, but am unable to make use of the smoothness of $P$ at this point. Any ideas about this?

Comment: You say that $\varphi$ is a chart on $\mathbb{RP}^n$ and $\psi$ is a chart on $\mathbb{RP}^k$, but then you write the expression $\varphi\circ\widetilde{P}\circ\psi^{-1}$. This is inconsistent. If the charts are defined where you say they are, then the expression you want to consider is $\psi\circ\widetilde{P}\circ\varphi^{-1}$.

Answer (score 10):

Let $P(x_0, \dots, x_n) = (P_0(x_0, \dots, x_n), \dots, P_k(x_0, \dots, x_n))$ where $P_0, \dots, P_k : \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \to \mathbb{R}$ are smooth homogeneous polynomials of degree $d$.

*If you had done this, I think, based on what you had already done, you would have been able to complete the proof. Just in case, I have included the proof below.*

---

Let $U_i = \{[x_0, \dots, x_n] \in \mathbb{RP}^n \mid x_i \neq 0\}$ and $\varphi_i : U_i \to \mathbb{R}^n$, given by

$$\varphi_i([x_0, \dots, x_n]) = \left(\frac{x_0}{x_i}, \dots, \frac{x_{i-1}}{x_i}, \frac{x_{i+1}}{x_i}, \dots, \frac{x_n}{x_i}\right)$$

with inverse $\varphi_i^{-1} : \mathbb{R}^n \to U_i$ given by $\varphi_i^{-1}(x_1, \dots, x_n) = (x_1, \dots, x_{i-1}, 1, x_{i+1}, \dots, x_n)$.

Let $V_j = \{[y_0, \dots, y_k] \in \mathbb{RP}^k \mid y_j \neq 0\}$ and $\psi_j : V_j \to \mathbb{R}^k$, given by

$$\psi_j([y_0, \dots, y_k]) = \left(\frac{y_0}{y_j}, \dots, \frac{y_{j-1}}{y_j}, \frac{y_{j+1}}{y_j}, \dots, \frac{y_k}{y_j}\right)$$

with inverse $\psi_j^{-1} : \mathbb{R}^k \to V_j$ given by $\psi_i^{-1}(y_1, \dots, y_k) = (y_1, \dots, y_{j-1}, 1, y_{j+1}, \dots, y_k)$.

For each $i$ and $j$ such that $U_i\cap\widetilde{P}^{-1}(V_j) \neq \emptyset$, we have the map

$$\psi_j\circ\widetilde{P}\circ\varphi_i^{-1} : \varphi_i^{-1}(U_i\cap\widetilde{P}^{-1}(V_j)) \to \psi_j(\widetilde{P}(U_i)\cap V_j)$$

given by

\begin{align*}
&(\psi_j\circ\widetilde{P}\circ\varphi_i^{-1})(x_1, \dots, x_n)\\ 
=&\ \psi_j(\widetilde{P}(\varphi_i^{-1}(x_1, \dots, x_n)))\\
=&\ \psi_j(\widetilde{P}(x_1, \dots, x_{i-1}, 1, x_{i+1}, \dots, x_n))\\
=&\ \psi_j(P_0(x_1, \dots, x_{i-1}, 1, x_{i+1}, \dots, x_n), \dots, P_k(x_1, \dots, x_{i-1}, 1, x_{i+1}, \dots, x_n))\\
=&\ \left(\frac{P_0(x_1, \dots, x_{i-1}, 1, x_{i+1}, \dots, x_n)}{P_j(x_1, \dots, x_{i-1}, 1, x_{i+1}, \dots, x_n)}, \dots, \frac{P_{j-1}(x_1, \dots, x_{i-1}, 1, x_{i+1}, \dots, x_n)}{P_j(x_1, \dots, x_{i-1}, 1, x_{i+1}, \dots, x_n)}, \frac{P_{j+1}(x_1, \dots, x_{i-1}, 1, x_{i+1}, \dots, x_n)}{P_j(x_1, \dots, x_{i-1}, 1, x_{i+1}, \dots, x_n)}, \dots, \frac{P_k(x_1, \dots, x_{i-1}, 1, x_{i+1}, \dots, x_n)}{P_j(x_1, \dots, x_{i-1}, 1, x_{i+1}, \dots, x_n)}\right).
\end{align*}

As $(x_1, \dots, x_n) \in \varphi_i^{-1}(U_i\cap\widetilde{P}^{-1}(V_j))$, $P_j(x_1, \dots, x_{i-1}, 1, x_i, \dots, x_n) \neq 0$, so $\psi_j\circ\widetilde{P}\circ\varphi_i^{-1}$ is smooth (rational functions are smooth on the complement of the zero locus of the denominator).

Therefore, $\widetilde{P} : \mathbb{RP}^n \to \mathbb{RP}^k$ is smooth.

---

An almost identical argument can be used to show an analogous result in the complex setting:

> If $P : \mathbb{C}^{n+1} \to \mathbb{C}^{k+1}$ is a degree $d$ homogeneous polynomial mapping, then $\widetilde{P} : \mathbb{CP}^n \to \mathbb{CP}^k$ given by $\widetilde{P}([z]) = [P(z)]$ is holomorphic.

Comment: Where did we use the assumption that $P$ is smooth and homogeneous of degree $d$?

Comment: Also, how do we know that $U_i\cap\widetilde{P}^{-1}(V_j)$ is open? It needs to be open in $\mathbb{RP}^n$.

Comment: @AlJebr: We use the smoothness of $P$ to conclude that $\psi_j\circ\widetilde{P}\circ\varphi_i^{-1}$ is smooth. Homogeneity was used to define the map $\widetilde{P}$ (if $P$ is not homogeneous, $\widetilde{P}$ is not well-defined). As $\widetilde{P}$ is continuous, $U_i\cap\widetilde{P}^{-1}(V_j)$ is open.

Comment: How do we know $\widetilde{P}$ is continuous?

Comment: This follows from the fact that we have a commutative diagram

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\} @>{P}>> \mathbb{R}^{k+1}\setminus\{0\}\\
@V{\pi_n}VV @VV{\pi_k}V \\
\mathbb{RP}^n @>{\widetilde{P}}>> \mathbb{RP}^k.
\end{CD}$$

Comment: How do we know the diagram commutes? I believe for the diagram to commute, we would need to know that $\widetilde{P}$ is continuous.

Comment: @AlJebr: No, you don't need that. Commutativity just means $\widetilde{P}\circ\pi_n = \pi_k\circ P$. The map $\widetilde{P}$ is defined so that this holds.

Comment: Right, but how do we know that holds though? Is it because $P$ takes lines ($1$-dim subspaces) to lines?

Comment: @AlJebr: Note that $(\widetilde{P}\circ\pi_n)(x) = \widetilde{P}(\pi_n(x)) = \widetilde{P}([x])$ while $(\pi_k\circ P)(x) = \pi_k(P(x)) = [P(x)]$. The diagram commutes because $\widetilde{P}([x]) = [P(x)]$ by definition.

Comment: Ok cool. I see now that it commutes. But how does commutativity imply continuity of $\widetilde{P}$?

Comment: Let $U \subseteq \mathbb{RP}^n$ be an open set. As $\pi_n$ is a quotient map, it is an open map, and therefore $V \subseteq \mathbb{RP}^n$ is open if and only if $\pi_n^{-1}(V)$ is open. So $\widetilde{P}^{-1}(U)$ is open if and only if $\pi_n^{-1}(\widetilde{P}^{-1}(U))$ is open. But $\pi_n^{-1}(\widetilde{P}^{-1}(U)) = (\widetilde{P}\circ\pi_n)^{-1}(U) = (\pi_k\circ P)^{-1}(U) = P^{-1}(\pi_k^{-1}(U))$ which is open as $\pi_k$ and $P$ are continuous.

Comment: In general, quotient maps are not open maps. Quotient maps do send saturated open subsets to open subsets.

Comment: @AlJebr: You are correct, but it is open in this case. In general, if $G$ is a group action on $X$, then the projection $\pi : X \to X/G$ is open. This is the case here where $X = \mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}$ and $G = \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ acting by scalar multiplication.

Comment: When proving that $\psi_j\circ\widetilde{P}\circ\varphi_i^{-1}$ is smooth and in the step of applying the map $\psi_j$, you divided by $P_j$. Aren’t we supposed to divide by the $j$-th coordinate, which is $P_{j-1}$ since we started by $P_0$? Sorry for asking in an old post. Thank you.

Comment: @Dima: Recall that $\psi_j([y_0, \dots, y_k]) = \left(\frac{y_0}{y_j}, \dots, \frac{y_{j-1}}{y_j}, \frac{y_{j+1}}{y_j}, \dots, \frac{y_k}{y_j}\right)$, so when calculating $\psi_j\circ\tilde{P}\circ\varphi_i^{-1}$, you divide by $P_j$.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry my bad. Thank you so much!